# Xdebug not working [not stopping at breakpoint] on Ubuntu 18.04, PhpStorm, Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, ubuntu, zend-framework, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using Zend Framework 3 with PhpStorm, I setup LAMP on Ubuntu 18.04.

When debugging code, I turn on debug icon [extension] in Chrome browser, then turn on start listening in PhpStorm, then I put breakpoints at homepage controller method from where the page loading, and then I refresh the page to check if it stops at the breakpoints.

I am not sure what I have missed in the setting, not able to debug the code. Any help is much appreciated.

**etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini**

```
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

**etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini**

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

**PHP version details :**

```
shoebaamir123@ubuntu:~$ php -v
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does "Run -> Web Server Debug Validation" output when you click "Validate" button? Have you created a deployment server configuration?

Comment: @Alexey "Run -> Web Server Debug Validation"  output -> "Path to create validation script : /var/www/html/crud" and "Url to validation script : http://127.0.0.1"

Comment: please update your question with a screenshot of its output

Comment: Also in information block it output, " Please, configure local and web path to validation script"

Comment: @Alexey I have added screenshot in question

Comment: After I click Validate, it out puts "Specified URL is not reachable, caused by : 'Request failed with status code 404'"

Comment: you need to create a local or remote web server config, I guess it's under "Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Deployment", then "+" and select the docroot of your project, where it places a test debug file to validate

Comment: Sidenote: your PHP language level is 5.6 yet your interpreter is 7.2.12 ;-)

Comment: @Alexey After I click "+" It shows me 6 options FTP, FTPS,SFTP, Local or mounted server, In place, Server group. Which one should I choose?

Comment: @lucid yes PHP language level its showing 5.6 and the field is disabled, how can i change it ?

Comment: depends on where your project files are located. My bet it should be "Local". Then select the folder where your document root is, enter the web server URL and switch to "Mappings" tab and fill the three fields in. Then try the validation script again and watch the access log of your web server to see where it tries to locate the temporary validation script, then adjust the paths in mappings accordingly until you get results in the validation script window

Comment: @Alexey After adjusting paths, It shows the output in validationo script window, but debugger still not stopping at breakpoint. I have attached screenshot.

Comment: Please show your xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug attempt. If Xdebug sees "debug me" flag (cookie in your case; although you have `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` so it will try to debug every single request) it should try to make a connection (and log that fact).

Comment: Can you add the content (if any) of `/tmp/xdebug_remote.log` to your question?

Comment: @Aamir Did you configured the IDE key inside the Chrome Debug extension?

Comment: You probably have the following in you composer.json: "php": "5.6", change it to     "php": "7.2" and it will change your PHP language level.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Remote Web Server" in the "Web Server Debug Validation" window and select there a server you created earlier as per my comment.

Comment: After I have selected "Remote Web Server" and validated it, it shows green checks in the list, but still not stopping at breakpoint.

Comment: 1. please replace the screenshot with the green checkmarks with remote web server in your question; 2. update your question with the way you launch the webpage when debugging, does this happen with the debug button from PHPStorm? Is the debug GET parameter passed to the browser and then web server?

Comment: I have added screenshot. When debugging code, I turn on debug icon[extension] in chrome browser, then turn on start listening in PHPSTORM, then I put breakpoints at homepage controller method from where the page loading, and then I refresh the webpage to check if it stops at the breakpoints. It's a Zend 3 application.

Comment: 1. can you add a debug configuration in PHPStorm ("Add configuration" button on your 4th screenshot) and specify 'crud server' as "Server", / as "Start URL", select any browser and name it somehow (doesn't matter how) and then 2. click "Debug" button, which is second to the right from "Add Configuration" and see if it stops then

Comment: also, to test, please place the breakpoint on the first line of index.php or your entry point, not in the controller

Comment: Added crud server

Comment: It shows on browser, This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Comment: in your 'crud server' server configuration change 127.0.0.1 with the correct hostname for your project - the one you're testing with in your browser

Comment: Now it is showing debug toolbar but not stopping at breakpoint in index.php

Comment: should I run local php server in terminal first ?
"php -S 127.0.0.0:8080 -t crud/public/ crud/public/index.php"
Because currently I'm just accesing the project from localhost/crud/public

Comment: it doesn't matter how you run your webserver, main thing is xdebug PHP module must be loaded. I was under impression you already running nginx or apache or anything else as the dialog reports it's able to connect both to 9001 port. I don't know what you mean when you're saying you access your project from "localhost/crud/public", but it it's the URL you put into your browser, the path must be configured in the "crud server" server config too. At this point I'm out of ideas, what I can tell is your server config: host, port, path must reflect the ones you're testing in your browser

Comment: Ok Thank Alexey, I will try to find out some way to work it. I think I have missed some configuration.

Comment: make sure to update your question with a solution and perhaps a guide. Don't replace the question/screenshots, though, just add UPDATE section and post there

Comment: Ok. I will add once I found the solution